# How do you test the disk integrity of your Android tablet's file system?

Tags: disk-drive

My Lenovo ThinkPad tablet is rather new (only a few months old), but I'm worried that it might be starting to contain some disk errors.

I just got a "Cannot read page from file system trouble ahead" error message from the LectureNotes application and I'm not sure what it means, especially since a Google for the error produced no results.

Anyways, is there a chkdisk, Hard Disk Sentinel, or something for the tablet's SSD drive that I can use?

Answer (score 14):

Tools like `fsck` would only check the file system. However, internal memory uses NAND-Flash, which should handle bad blocks itself with internal "bad block tables".

For file system checks, you would find a corresponding article on XDA: ["[HOW TO] Check your filesystem (a la 'fsck')"](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165870). Fortunately, there's also an article on the NAND-Flash level: ["Is there a tool for checking the nand memory for bad blocks?"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1421029).

As this is a very special thing (and most likely not interesting for too many of our readers), I permit myself to not elaborating the details, and just linking the relevant sources ;)