# How can I run a consistency check on my removable MicroSD card?

Tags: external-sd, storage, file-system, maintenance, exfat

I own an Android device with a removable MicroSD card. The card uses either FAT32 or ExFAT technology. These are "non-journaling filesystem" technologies, so the data on the cards can become corrupted in certain cases.

Perhaps I should run a consistency check (e.g. `fsck` / Chkdsk / ScanDisk) every so often.

How can I run a consistency check on my MicroSD card, without having to plug the card into a PC?

Comment: This question is about **how**. If you also wonder about **when**, please see: ["When should I run a consistency check on my removable MicroSD card?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171938/when-should-i-run-a-consistency-check-on-my-removable-microsd-card)