# When should I run a consistency check on my removable MicroSD card?

Tags: external-sd, storage, file-system, maintenance, exfat

I own an Android device with a removable MicroSD card. The card uses either FAT32 or ExFAT technology. These are "non-journaling filesystem" technologies, so the data on the cards can become corrupted in certain cases.

Perhaps I should run a consistency check (e.g. `fsck` / Chkdsk / ScanDisk) every so often.

A) How often should I run a consistency check on my MicroSD card?

B) Also, if my device sometimes freezes and I must power it off using the power button, must I run a consistency check every time?

Comment: This question is about **when**. If you also wonder about **how**, please see: ["How can I run a consistency check on my removable MicroSD card?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171937/how-can-i-run-a-consistency-check-on-my-removable-microsd-card)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you don't need to run consistency checks on filesystems manually. `vold` runs filesystem check ([`fsck.exfat`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/fs/Exfat.cpp#34) or [`fsck_msdos`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/fs/Vfat.cpp#55)) everytime before [mounting](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/model/PublicVolume.cpp#96) a supported filesystem (including `exFAT` and `FAT[N]`) on secondary external storage.