# Droid Turbo 2 storage doesn't clear

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, motorola-droid-2

We often get out of storage messages on our Motorola Droid Turbo 2 phone. We delete an App, and, say it's a 100 MB app, we only see about 10 MB free up. Likewise we've transferred and deleted gigabytes of pictures and videos from the phone, but only a tiny amount of space gets freed up. We're deleting and deleting and deleting, but we still have no room.

Right now, looking at "Internal shared storage" - It shows 23.27 GB used of 24.06 GB but only 5.06 GB used for Apps and 7.32 GB used for imaged, 18.73 MB for videos, 0 for Audio, 475 MB for other and only 1.34 MB for cached data (so it's not cached data). Those don't add up to anywhere near 23.27 GB! Apps and Images numbers go down as we delete, but the total GB used barely moves!

[image: Internal Shared Storage Screen 1]

[image: Internal Shared Storage Screen 2]

What is happening? How can we get our storage back?

Per Robert's comment, we downloaded Disk Info, screen shot below. But, all it did was show that we used most of the "Data". There's no insight as to what is using it, or why as soon as we delete apps, photos, and videos, most of the amount we just freed appears to be instantly taken back up.

[image: DiskInfo Data Partition]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: No, in the question on that thread, if you add up the subcomponents they are very close to the total. It doesn’t explain why mine doesn’t add up to a value even close to the total.

Comment: Please see my answer to that question. I don't think there's any space left for confusion related to Android storage.

Comment: To total storage size shown in the settings has often nothing to do with reality. Use an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) to see the real values.

Comment: Irfan, your answer doesn’t provide a solution to our issue. Our phone is not rooted, so we can’t do anything you suggest.

Comment: @Robert We got enough free to download DiskInfo and used it [Fortunately it's a very small App]. All we can find is that "Data" used reported by DiskInfo is equivalent to the total shown in "Internal Shared Storage". We can't find any information on what is actually using up that data and why or how to free it... ultimately we need to be able to delete whatever is taking up this space. We keep deleting apps, photos, videos, etc. but not getting our space back.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? If you have Android 8 or newer it will then perform a file-system check (see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171936/2241). May be this recovers the lost space.

Comment: We have tried rebooting and it didn't help. We have Android 7.0 Nougat